# EF Core - API Site: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I know there are plenty of other threads covering this topic, but none of the solutions appear to have helped. Hence the creation of this one. Sorry for the lengthy Post!

**The problem:**
I am running an .Net Core API Website using EF Core. Naturally I am ensuring the context is Transient and created per request. Passing the Context through classes to ensure it's not recreated or executing two queries at the same time. I can debug and follow my code through without error. But once in production environment, I still run into this problem, and I've exhausted all of the top google result solutions...

**The actual error:**

> A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

```
services.AddDbContext<APIContext>((serviceprovider, options) =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection"));
     options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceprovider);
});
```

**I've tried:**
Several different ways of registering my context, using all the different constructors like below. I've even tried creating as a DbContextPool instead with no luck.

```
services.AddDbContext<APIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Every one of my controllers or middleware, have the DBContext passed via the constructor as DI. Despite a few Async calls (all using await). I can not find any area that may cause this error. I've added a code sample below following a recent error, code removed for brevity.

To provide some context, every request enters my middleware for security, it's the catch in here that notifies me of the error, so I'm not sure if that's the cause? Am I registering the Interface /Middleware correctly?

```
//Register Request logger
services.AddTransient<IRequestLogger, RequestLoggerConcrete>();

//Constructor for Request Logger
public RequestLoggerConcrete(APIContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

//Method Called in Middleware
public async void InsertLoggingData(LoggerEntity loggerTB)
{
   try
   {
        loggerTB.LoggerID = 0;
        _context.Loggers.Add(loggerTB);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
     throw;
   }
}

//The Middleware Constructor
public ApiKeyValidatorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IValidateRequest ivalidaterequest, IRequestLogger irequestlogger)
{
      _next = next;
      _IValidateRequest = ivalidaterequest;
      _IRequestLogger = irequestlogger;
}

//Middleware Execution
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
 {
      try
      { 
        ..... Validation - API Code Code Removed .... 
        _IRequestLogger.InsertLoggingData(loggertb);
         await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
       }
       catch(Exception ex) {
         ...Notify Email Removed...
       }
 }

//Controller Init
public SMSController(APIContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}

//Sample Method
public ActionResult GetMessages()
{
   return Json(SMSMessages.GetMessages(_db));
}


//Class Code
public static SMSMessageSimple GetMessages(APIContext _db)
{
     var lst = (from sms in _db.SMSs
                where sms.SentResultCode == null
                && sms.SentToDevice == false
                select new SMSMessage()
                {
                    message = sms.Message,
                    recepient = sms.ToNumber,
                    id = sms.SMSID.ToString()
                }).ToArray();

     var DistinctGuids = lst.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.id)).Distinct();
     DateTime dtNow = System.DateTime.Now.ToGMT();
     _db.SMSs.Where(w => DistinctGuids.Contains(w.SMSID)).Update(u => new SMSEntity()
     {
          SentToDevice = true,
          ModifiedBy = "API",
          ModifiedDate = dtNow
     });

      return new SMSMessageSimple(lst);
}
```

I get this error on methods that don't even make any calls to the Database, yet on some, the log is inserted but the error persists..  Could it be the app pool? If two separate requests are made at the same time?

Any guidance is appreciated!!

Comment: Also validate that you aren't returning any `IEnumerable` that might be connected to an open DataReader.  IE always calling `.ToList()` or similar before exiting a method.